# Javascript - add class to element, remove from siblings

Tags: javascript, jquery

Code is very basic (you can get the idea when you look at it, no need to explain), somehow it doesn't work... can anyone please tell me what am i doing wrong?

```js
$("ul li").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('cell-selected')
    .parent().siblings().find('.cell-selected').removeClass('cell-selected');
});
```

```css
.cell-selected {
  color: #fff;
  background: #5b2200;
  border-color: #ce5209;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="cell-selected"><a>First</a></li>
  <li><a>Second</a></li>
  <li><a>Third</a></li>
</ul>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dantini23/vt46qucq/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("ul li").click(function() {

  $(this).addClass('cell-selected')
      .siblings().removeClass('cell-selected')
});
```

You are looking `siblings` of selected `li`.So,no need of  `parent()` and  `find('.cell-selected').`

Comment: Thanks, i guess im adding to much "noise" to my code

Answer (score 0):

You can try with it:

```
 $("ul li").click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('cell-selected').siblings().removeClass('cell-selected');
 });
```